# Under powered Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: power, usb-power, pi-b+

I don't know for sure if it's the power supply I'm using but I am getting under voltage warning on my Raspberry Pi B+ when overclocked and not overclocked (more frequently when overclocked).

I've tried 4 different phone chargers - HTC, Samsung, and 2 off brands, and 3 different USB cables. I've also tried using the Pi without anything plugged into the USB. I am planning on getting a powered USB Hub, because I want to use a wifi dongle along with my Xbox controller.

I just want to know what the consensus is for overclocking a Pi on whether or not it needs a stronger PSU or it's because the USB ports are drawing too much power.

Also, any recommendations for a reliable PSU and powered USB hub?

Comment: You do not often get something for nothing.  You overclock to get more speed, that requires more power.  Buy an inexpensive meter and measure the voltage at the Pi.

Comment: How much overclocking do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phone power supplies are not as reliable as dedicated switching power supplies. You can buy a switching power supply for the rPi for very little money ([this one for example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LSEOTYK)). A powered hub might work, but depending on the hub you might get feedback issues. A separate, well spec-ed power supply (at least 1.5A for rPi. 2A for rPi2) is the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't planning on using the powered hub to power the PI, just using it for the USB devices so they wouldn't be drawing more power from the PI. I will invest in a better power supply then.

Answer (score 0):

Phone chargers are chargers of unknown specifications. They are not regulated 5 Volt power supplies. You risk damage to your RPi and lots of frustration. Spend $5 or $6 on fleebay and buy a 5V 3A plug-pack and never need to worry about under-voltage problems again. This has been my experience.